# Make G++ use my lib automatically

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, include, shared-libraries

I have an already built library made of this files:

- A bunch of headers.
- A .so file (libmylib.so).

I want to compile a c++ program (sample.cpp), where I included the headers, and where I need to use the library. This is what I've done, and it's working:

- Put the headers in usr/local/include.
- Put the .so file in usr/local/lib.
- Compile the program in this way: g++ sample.cpp -lmylib.

My question is: why is it not working if I omit -lmylib from the last line?
Is there a way to install the library such that I don't need to put it every time in the g++ command?

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with specifying which library you want to link with? I have 1500 lib*.so in /usr/lib, and I sure don't want every program linked with all of them...

Comment: Ah, you probably want a way to mention `-lmylib` in the header, have the compiler use it to mark the `.o`, and then have the linker notice it and link with `-lmylib`. This exists on some systems, but not linux, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

What libs are used by default depends on some setting in the compiler/linker,
but it´s not "every lib in usr/local/lib" or any directory, just some specific names
(or even just a single one). Call `g++ -v` or `g++ -dumpspecs` to list it (and more stuff)

So, either rebuild your compiler with your own lib list, or specify it manually everytime.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Depends on how it was build, or not? (At least if I remember correctly, there is a compile-time setting too).